# Why is db.findAll() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I create and instance of database with sequelize, but it does not have methods like findAll(). What am i doing wrong?

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const router = require('express').Router();

const db = new Sequelize('web-prog', 'postgres', '1234', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db
        .findAll()
        .then(itemlist => res.json(itemlist))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});

module.exports = { db, router };
```

//then i require it like this

```
const db = require('./database').db;
```

> TypeError: db.findAll is not a function

Comment: It's a Promise.

Comment: @TríPhan it *returns* a Promise, but that isn't why it's not found, it's because it is on the Model not Sequelize instance.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `findAll()` on the `Sequelize` connection, however this method is found on the `Model` which is why you are getting the error.

*Create a Model called MyModel*

```
module.exports = function Model(db, DataTypes) {
  const MyModel = db.define('myModel', {/* fields */, {/* options */});
  return MyModel;
}
```

Then you would load the models -

```
  const db = require('./database').db;
  const myModel = db.import(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'myModel'));
  myModel.findAll() <-- this will exist and return a promise
```